# Display image thumbs uploaded with PaperClip in a grid

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to display six images uploaded with PaperClip in a grid type fashion.

Whatever I try, the images only display in one line. If I change the class to `gallery` it instead shows one image per line.

I have also tried `#each_slice` with no luck, and using `index` was my last attempt.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="page-header"><h1>My Work</h1></div>
  <div class="media">
    <% @documents.in_groups_of(3, false).each_with_index do |document_group, index| %>
      <% document_group.each do |document| %>
        <div class="media-left">
          <% if index < 3 %>
          <%= link_to image_tag(document.doc.url, class: 'media-object', size:"108x152"), document.doc.url, target: '_blank' %>
          <%= link_to 'Remove', document_path(document), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading"><%= document.title %></h4>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>  
  </div>
</div>
```

**documents_controller.rb**

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @documents = Document.order('created_at')
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you looked at flexbox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a problem to be solved with Ruby. Are your thumbs a fixed width? If so, you could put them in a div of 3x{thumb width + whatever margins, padding is needed}, allowing room for only three on any line.

Or, you could use [nth child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selectors maybe?